# scroll on top of page after history.goBack() - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```js
const HeaderBackButton: FC = () => { const history = useHistory();

return ( <> <button className={styles.button} onClick={() => { history.goBack(); window.scrollTo(0, 0); }>
```

Comment: Can't you use `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` when you go back to your expected component ? as in not after `history.goBack();` but inside some lifecycle function (like `componentDidMount()`) when you go back ? Maybe just check the history and match the url to check if you got back from the component that had `history.goBack();` and only then scroll to top ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add in your parent component `useEffect` that will have pathname in his dependencies

```
const Layout: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
  }, [history.location.pathname]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <main className={styles.content}>{children}</main>
      <Footer menuItems={footerMenu} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Layout;
```

Comment: is there any way we can make this faster or with no animations? it might affect the user expoerience.

Comment: just remove behavior property